# How to scrape the total number of customer reviews from the Amazon website on a particular product?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the total number of customer reviews from the Amazon page, using python and beautiful soup library. The details like customer ratings, stars are getting scraped, but not the review count.

```
def get_total_review(soup):
    try:
        # total_review1= soup.find("div", attrs={'id': 'filter-info-section'}).string.strip()
        total_review1= soup.find("div", attrs={'data-hook': 'cr-filter-info-section'}).string.strip()

        total_review = sototal_review1.find("div", attrs={'class':'a-row a-spacing-base a-size-base'}).string.strip()

    except AttributeError:
        total_review = ""

    return total_review
```

[image]

I tried adding every particular id, class but the review count isn't getting displayed ('3,432' in this case, as you can see in the image):

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.